# Why does it insert it more than once?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Trying to insert " _ " before uppercase letters but it inserts more than once.

Instead of
["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " _ ", "W", "o", "l", "r", "d"] it prints ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', 'W', 'o', 'l', 'r', 'd']

```
new = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]

for i in range(len(new)):
    print(i)
    if new[i].isupper():
        new.insert(i, "_")

print(new)
```

Comment: Take a pen and a paper and follow the logic, line by line. You should see the problem.

Comment: Great advice :) but its pen not pan.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen Indeed, a pan would be less effective for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, each call to `new.insert(i, "_")` changes `new` so that the uppercase letter that was previously at index `i` is now at index `i + 1`, since you have just inserted the character `_` at index `i` and pushed he uppercase letter (and every item that comes after it in the list `new`) one position higher.

One way to fix this would be to loop through `new` in reverse order using python's built-in function [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```py
new = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]

for i in reversed(range(len(new))):
    #print(i)
    if new[i].isupper():
        new.insert(i, "_")

print(new)
```

Now, after examining the character at index `i`, detecting that it's uppercase, and inserting `_` at `i`, the next loop iteration examines the character at position `i - 1`, which was unaffected by the prior iteration's call to `new.insert(i, "_")`.

Output:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '_', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Answer (score 3):

Because after you `insert` `'_'` at index `i`, the uppercase letter (`W`) is moved to the right and thus gets the index `i+1`. Now the for loop iteration completes, and `i` gets incremented and becomes `i+1`, but guess what is at index `i+1`? (Hint: `W`) So, this is a cycle that only exhausts when the for loop iterates `len(new)` times. Below is what the execution might look like:

- (i=0): new[i] is 'h'
- (i=1): new[i] is 'e'
- (i=2): new[i] is 'l'
- (i=3): new[i] is 'l'
- (i=4): new[i] is 'o'
- (i=5): new[i] is 'W' --> `insert '_'` --> 'W' moves to `new[i+1]`
- (i=6): new[i] is 'W' --> `insert '_'` --> and this pattern repeats

A simple solution would be to run backwards. As now, `insert '_'` will push 'W' to the right, while we are moving to the left; therefore, we won't end up in the cycle like before.

```py
new = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
start = len(new) - 1 # last element
end = -1 # one prior to the first element
         # remember, range end is non-inclusive,
         # so it goes till index 0
step = -1 # decrement to move backwards
for i in range(start, end, step):
    if new[i].isupper():
        new.insert(i, "_")
print(new)
```

Comment: It means that running from 8 to 0.

The first parameters is len(new)-1 which is 8

The second one is -1 means stop when reach -1

The third one is -1 is the step, after each loop the iterator will be minus 1

Comment: I understand it, I just want you to improve the answer by adding that details :)

Comment: Okay, hope it helps. If this is good, you can mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list:

```
new = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]

result = []
for i in range(len(new)):
    if new[i].isupper():
        result.append("_")
    result.append(new[i])

print(result)
```